# Delete wrapped lines?

Tags: key-bindings, cut-copy-paste, wrapping

How to delete wrapped lines?

I imagined something like `gdd` and `gD` but they did not work as expected, in a similar fashion to `gj` and `gk` to move through wrapped lines.

It would be really useful to have a way to delete multi-lined wraps.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in Insert Mode, doesn't help with that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there's no default mapping for this. You could make one for yourself though. I would be careful about mapping `gdd` or `gD` because [`gd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#gd) and [`gD`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#gD) already have functions that are really useful. I'm going to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> just as a suggestion.

```
nnoremap <A-d> g^dg$g^
```

Comment: Thats right, I already mapped it myself :P but it was a workaround and it doesn't accept input numbers for range. Alts never work for me, and what are the pre-existing functions of `gdd` and `gD` though? :)

Comment: I linked the documentation for you. :P But they find the local definition of the word under the cursor.

Comment: Btw I did `noremap gD g^dg$g^` (and `gdd` too). I think `d$` would delete until the end of the whole line.

Comment: Good point, added.

Comment: I think you should replace the last `0` with `g^` too though, for the sake of wraps :P